# How to get all unallocated spaces from extended partition via WMI?

Tags: windows, wmi, disk-partitioning

I'm trying to get all unallocated spaces (as a list of <offset,size> pairs) on a disk.
Everything is good as far there aren't any extended partitions on the disk - I just list `Win32_DiskPartition`s associated with the selected `Win32_DiskDrive` and analyze their offsets and sizes to find gaps between them.

If, however, there's an extended partition, things get complicated - it is like a black box and the internal partitions aren't among objects associated with my `Win32_DiskDrive`. I tried listing the extended partition's associated objects, but there are no "internal" `Win32_DiskPartition`s linked to the extended partition, only`Win32_LogicalDisk`s, but they don't give me any information about the partition's actual geometry

It tried using diskpart for this purpose, but it rounds all the partition sizes to GB, and I need them to be exact. Also it's locale-dependent, which makes it hard it parse the output (my app needs to be as locale-independent as possible)